# Faster way of calculating how many ways can $2n$ elements be paired?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So the problem is in how many ways `2n` elements can be paired, my approach was multiply all odd numbers less then `2n`.

```
(2n-1)*(2n-3)*...*1
```

but my professor claimed it can be done much faster in algorithmic sense, but I don't really see the way to do so. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not comp-sci theory. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Combinatorics, eh? I'll send you down the right path: You are looking for the number of unique combinations of 2 elements from 2n elements, where repetition is not allowed (so [1, 2] == [2, 1]). Check out [this website](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html) for a great introduction to the concept.

Comment: thanks for the link!

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood and the prof wanted a closed form? Perhaps: (2n)!/(n! * 2^n)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking how to compute the number of two-character strings from a list of 2n characters? For example, given `[a,b,c,d]`, which would generate `[ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd]`, and you want to know how many there are?

Comment: This is often called the ___double factorial___ of `2n-1`. You can find some info and references on [Wikipedia: Double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) and [OEIS A001147 (Double factorial of odd numbers)](https://oeis.org/A001147).

Answer (score 1):

Update: This is probably not what you are asking:

Your question rephrased: How many ways to choose two elements from a set of 2n elements? Also known as combination, the binomial coefficient or choice number and read ["n choose k"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Combination.html).

You can take the formula `n! / (k! * (n - k)!)`, replace `n` by `2n` and then simplify it algebraically to `(2n - 1) * n`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

def pairs(n):
    return (2 * n - 1) * n

# there is only one pair for an 2n element set {0, 1}
print(pairs(1)) # prints 1

# pairs of {0, 1, 2, 3} = {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}
print(pairs(2)) # prints 6
```

Comment: (That is not [user2196638](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2196638/user2196638)'s question rephrased, let alone her professor's. That one seems to be asking for the number of ways to form _n_ intersection-free two element subsets from a set of _2n_ elements. As the first element needs to be paired anyway, let's just tally _2n-1_ for it and repeat for _2n-2_, leading to the product from the question. While I can come up with "simpler" formulae, I don't see how to compute it exactly `much faster [algorithmically]`, even assuming operations on integers the size of the result taking constant time.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are calculating (2n)!/(n!2^n), because multiplicating all even numbers less or equal to 2n gives:

`2n * (2(n-1)) * (2(n-2)) * ... * 2 = n!2^n`

Algortithmically factorials can be computed in specific routines in almost constant times. One way to do it is to use the Stirling approximation formula (for large enough numbers)

`n! ~ sqrt(2 pi n)(n/e)^n`